# deploySafe function transaction is stuck in txpool as pending on Polygon Mainnet

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core, safe

I'm trying to deploy a Safe contract using `safeFactory.deploySafe` with certain transaction options, but the deployment appears to be stuck as pending in the transaction pool. Here is the sample code I'm using:

```typescript
const options: EthersTransactionOptions = {
  gasPrice: 250000000000, // Optional
  gasLimit: 936258
}

const callback = (txHash: string): void => {
  console.log({ txHash })
}

const safeSdk = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig, saltNonce, options, callback })
```

One of the transactions that is stuck as pending in the pool can be found here: [Transaction on PolygonScan](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x4400818522043c3bfe33af6b18b57ee3f23ae1570df4ee04f2079c0fcbf24219)

Answer (score 1):

A stuck transaction happens because network operators are not incentivized enough to move your transaction from the mempool to include it in a block. Maybe resending the same transaction with more gas could help get it unstuck.

Hope it helps,
Louis

Comment: Hi! You may want to explain the answer more (i.e. that stuck in txpool doesn't have to do with the code, it's about the gas price) - that way it can help other people with similar problems.